# Will MG Chemicals Positive Developer 418 Develop pre-sensitized circuit boards?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I'm trying to find a cheaper alternative to the Datak [stuff](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_156734_-1) ($18 for 4oz!), and I came across [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005T8QLCY) (MG Chemicals 418). I'm wondering if it will work with the pre-sensitized Datak boards I'm using (ex [here](http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_2097117_-1)), or if Datak boards require Datak developer.

Answer (score 4):

WHAT!!?? Those prices for NaOH are pure robbery!

Anyway, here's a trick how to compare chemicals: 
Every manufacturer has to provide material safety datasheet for each potentially dangerous chemical product. You basically go to Google and write `product name MSDS` and you get the document. It will contain the ingredients for the product. If you had some very basic chemistry training, you should be able to identify what's inside.

So for MG Chemicals 418, we can see in the [MSDS](http://www.mgchemicals.com/downloads/msds/english/sds-418-liquid.pdf) that main ingredient is sodium hydroxide (NaOH) and it's 7% to 11% by weight and that the rest is deionized water.

I couldn't dig up the material safety datasheet for that exact developer (but you should be able to request it from manufacturer or distributor), but [here](http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/616411%20MSDS.pdf)'s the concentrated version. If you look up ingredients, you'll see that it's "caustic soda" which is one of the names for NaOH.

Based on this, we can see that the active ingredient in both products is the same, so they should basically work the same. Only possible difference could be the concentration, since I couldn't dig up the MSDS for the exact product you've been using.

Also here in Serbia, 1 kg of NaOH costs between $1 and $2 and you can make around 100 l of developer with it, because usual concentration is 10 g of NaOH per liter.

Comment: Wow, I didn't think to check the MSDS for the actual content. Great tip.

Comment: @sacredfaith Best thing about it is that companies must provide it to you, so they can't actually hide what's inside. They can make it hard to read though.

Comment: Awesome. I might have to consult my friends Google and Dusty Chemistry Textbook to parse it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: It does not say that the remainder is *all* DI water- there could be non-hazardous ingredients included that make the product better such as surfactants (wetting agents) or anti-foaming agents.

Comment: A 90:10 solution of distilled water and NaOH ate EVERYTHING off the board in less than a minute including the photo sensitive traces that showed up initially. I'm guessing that ratio might be too strong.

Answer (score 0):

It should, but it's cheap enough that testing it is probably worthwhile.  There really isn't a very wide variety of photoetching chemistries in PCB manufacturing, so while the timing might be different, it will probably perform the same function just fine.

Comment: I think you're right - I'll be purchasing some soon, and let you know how it goes.